# Send HTML email in Outlook 2016

Tags: email, html, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have created an HTML page with modified from a template I got.... I want to send as a HTML based newsletter in Outlook 2016.

However the guides I see as "insert as text" do not apply to Outlook 2016 as there is no dropdown for inserting files for that in the 2016 version.

I am wondering how I go about being able to send this HTML email?

Comment: The issue you have is `Outlook rewrites the email HTML before sending it out, which usually removes all media queries and can sometimes otherwise warp your display.` [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931900/getting-my-html-into-email) and [Source](https://www.outlook-apps.com/insert-html-to-outlook-emails/).
 I know this is a bad answer/comment as it doesn't answer the question, but consider a different tool for email newsletters (such as Thunderbird)...

Comment: You are better off using a third party system like Mailchimp for this.

Answer (score 4):

The "insert as text" option *is* still available in Outlook 2016, but you have to un-hide the old "Attach File" button. Use that instead of the new "Attach File..." button on the ribbon.

From https://www.msoutlook.info/question/classic-attach-file-button:

> 1. File-> Options-> Quick Access Toolbar
> 2. Set the “Choose commands from” dropdown list to: All Commands.
> 3. Select the “Attach File” command.
>
>    - Make sure you do not select the “Attach File…” command as that is the new menu button.
> 4. Press the "Add > > " button.
> 5. Press OK to close the Options dialog and return to Outlook.
>      [image: Screenshot of steps to add the Attach File button]

Once you have the old "Attach File" button back:

1. Click the "Attach file" button in your Quick Access toolbar
2. Select your file ending in .html
3. Select "Insert as Text."

[image: screenshot of steps to inject HTML into an Outlook message body]

Answer (score 0):

Another program you could use is ContactMonkey. It's an add-in for Outlook and allows you to insert and send fully responsive HTML email templates straight from Outlook itself. It's a pretty new feature to the tool and I think it will solve the exact issue you're having! It's perfect for sending newsletters from Outlook without having to use another email provider, it also tracks everything too!

I actually work for them so if you need any help in using it I can definitely help you out! Here's a full how to guide explaing exactly how you can send HTML emails from Outlook.
https://www.contactmonkey.com/blog/how-to-send-employee-newsletter-in-outlook

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  You identify a tool and include a link to the details.  But readers need to go somewhere else to get the "how" part of your answer, and if that link ever goes bad or is unavailable, this answer won't contain the answer to "how".  Could you expand your answer to make it self contained?  Include the essential information from the link and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.