# How can I re-send an HTML email with embedded images?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, images, html, base64

I have a system-generated HTML email that includes base-64 images in the content.

```
<img style='display:block; width:100px;height:100px;' id='base64image'                 
       src='data:image/jpeg;base64, <!-- base64 data -->' />
```

After reviewing the original system-generated email, I need to make edits (to the text, not the image) and send the email to others.

However, when I try to copy or forward it to someone else, the image is missing.

How can I re-send the email after editing it, without losing the base64 images?

Comment: I've found the answer to https://superuser.com/questions/1049561/send-html-email-in-outlook-2016 to also answer this question. However, as the answer to that question has not been accepted, I'm unable to flag this question as a duplicate.

Comment: I've flagged the duplicate.